# how to check length in Angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-material, variable-length

I have normal tag components and super tag component. I've imported both component in my Edit Page Component. I'm trying make the user have at least 1 normal tag and super tag before they exist/close Edit page but not too sure how I can check the length so I would be really appreciated if I can get any suggestion or help.

I've imported the super tag component and normal tag component like this in

Edit page component.HTML

```html
<div class="super-container">
    <div class="tag-header"> Super Tags </div>
    <mat-hint class="hint">A minimum of one Super Tag is required for creating a Workspace</mat-hint>
    <mc-manage-super-tags [workspace]="workspace" (removed)="superRemoved($event)"></mc-manage-super-tags>
</div>

<div class="tag-container">
    <div class="tag-header"> Tags </div>
    <mat-hint class="hint">A minimum of one Tag is required for creating a Workspace</mat-hint>
    <mc-tags [workspace]="workspace" [removable]="true" [selectable]="true" [canAdd]="true" [editMode]="true" [getAllTags]="true" (added)="tagAdded($event)" (removed)="tagRemoved($event)"> </mc-tags>
</div>
```

Edit Page Component.TS

```
// This is how I add Normal Tag in the backend

  tagAdded(tag: string) {
    this.tagService.addTag(this.workspace.guid, 'workspace', tag).pipe(takeUntil(this.death$)).subscribe((tag) => {
      const foundTag = this.workspace.tags.find(t => t.tag === tag.tag);
      if (!foundTag) {
        this.workspace.tags.push(tag);
      } else {
        foundTag.pending = false;
        foundTag.tag = tag.tag;
        foundTag.type = tag.type;
      }
    })
    this.snackbar.open(tag + " has been added as tag.", " ", {duration: 2500});
  }

//I want to check here if user have at least 1 or not. Right now it's not working

  close(){
    if(this.tagAdded.length >= 1 ){
      this.router.navigate(['workspace']);
    }else{
      this.snackbar.open("Error: must have at least 1 tag", "", {duration: 2500})
    }}
```

I'm not sure If I'm supposed to put that logic inside normal component and supertag component or I can just do that in Edit page component like what I'm trying to do right now.

[image]

Comment: you are trying to check the length of a function.. instead of `this.tagAdded.length` you gotta `this.workspace.tags.length` I think. i don't know how is your structure so can't help that much

Comment: can you please create the  stackblitz so i can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are pushing tags in workspace object `this.workspace.tags.push(tag);` and this workspace object is used in both the component(super and normal) so you can check the length of tags inside workspace object like this:

```
this.workspace.tags.length >= 1
```

Hope it will work. If not please create stackblitz for your question so i can help you more.